# iteration over object of object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following structure

```
[
  {
    "name": null
    "match": [{
                 "id": 0,
                 "location": ""

             "awayTeam": {
                     "id": 1568,
                     "teamName": "Manly United" },
                 "homeTeam": {
                     "id": 1523,
                     "teamName": "Sydney FC Youth" },
                     "matchDataProvider": [{
                            "id": 2953046,
                         "updatedDate": null }],
                 "matchPunditPrediction": [],
                 "matchResult": null,
                     "userMatchPrediction": []
               }]
   }
]
```

I need to iterate over the match element and retrieve properties

Comment: is the structure constant? as there is outside array. Will there be multiple objects that you want to iterate over all of them?

Comment: Hi, Yes the match element will be constant. I have only described one element

Comment: You want to iterate array in html component?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let item of myData.match | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>

Comment: I currently have this in my html but this does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can do by:
arr = your full array.

```
arr.forEach(obj => {
  obj.match.forEach(m => {
    // This contains the match object.
    console.log(m);
    console.log(m.id);
  })
})
```

For html.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myData">
  <div *ngFor="let match of item.match | json"> {{ match }} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I need to use this in a component in angular. Can you show the syntax

Comment: Can you show me the code from your component.ts? Do you want to display the data in your template?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let item of myData.match | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>

Comment: This is what i have so far.

Comment: I updated the answer. {{ match }} is the final match object of each iteration.

Comment: sorry I get this error message Cannot find a differ supporting object

Comment: Can you add the code of how the myDate is being populated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194055/discussion-between-user1572257-and-muhammad-kamran).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same array structure.In normal java logic we know that,we can element value by iterating two times for loop.So I tried to do same .I tried to write ngFor to iterate first array but I got the error as **Found [object] instead of [Object object]**.Well this is surely not our fault but angulars ngFor loop only work with a proper array structure,it throws error when you iterate such kind of array structure.

After So many research I found one hack,

In your component file just write below code.

```
hack(val) {
    return Array.from(val);
  }
```

This will make array upon array. Magic is ,Angular finds this as proper array structure and it will not give error after.

Now when you write ngFor in html ,just write like this.

```
*ngFor="let variablename of hack(arrayObjectname)"
```

after this, if you need to write ngFor again for inside array,you still can write now :).This hack might show error in your code platform but it will run fine in browser.

I hope this will help you to solve your issue :)